# Apply variable number of filter conditions to a javascript array while traversing it only once?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, performance, filter

I have a javascript array of nested data that holds data which will be displayed to the user.

The user would like to be able to apply 0 to n filter conditions to the data they are looking at.

In order to meet this goal, I need to first find elements that match the 0 to n filter conditions, then perform some data manipulation on those entries. An obvious way of solving this is to have several filter statements back to back (with a conditional check inside them to see if the filter needs to be applied) and then a map function at the end like this:

```
var firstFilterList = _.filter(myData, firstFilterFunction);
var secondFilterList = _.filter(firstFilterList, secondFilterFunction);
var thirdFilterList = _.filter(secondFilterList, thirdFilterFunction);
var finalList = _.map(thirdFilterList, postFilterFunction);
```

In this case however, the javascript array would be traversed 4 times. A way to get around this would be to have a single filter that checks all 3 (or 0 to n) conditions before determining if there is a match, and then, inside the filter at the end of the function, doing the data manipulation, however this seems a bit hacky and makes the "filter" responsible for more than one thing, which is not ideal. The upside would be that the javascript Array is traversed only once.

Is there a "best practices" way of doing what I am trying to accomplish?

EDIT: I am also interested in hearing if it is considered bad practice to perform data manipulation (adding fields to javascript objects etc...) within a filter function.

Comment: Small correction: you're filtering an array, not a JSON Array. A JSON array is a textual representation of an array.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? when you are looking for *best practice*, first start by telling what you want to achieve and then what your approach is. This way readers can understand the requirement and help you in better way

Comment: I believe you can have the best of both worlds by keeping the filter functions, and defining a combined filter function utilising the individual filters. That is just my opinion.

Comment: @Rajesh What I am trying to achieve is both filtering an array with 0 to n filters and manipulating data in that filtered array, all while traversing the array a minimal number of times. My approach is currently highlighted in the last paragraph of my question.

Comment: I wonder why it's important to traverse a minimum number of times. Is your array so large that the performance hit is noticeable? If evidence suggests this is a slow part of the process and it's affecting usability, sure, work to optimize it. Otherwise, best practice is to write it in such a way that someone else reading your code can understand the intent easily. In most cases, readability is of greater worth than speedup.

Comment: to the edit, yes, inside fitering, mutation the object is bad practice. better use a mpaaing instead with a new object.

Answer (score 3):

You could collect all filter functions in an array and check every filter with the actual data set and filter by the result. Then take your mapping function to get the wanted result.

```
var data = [ /* ... */ ],
    filterFn1 = () => Math.round(Math.random()),
    filterFn2 = (age) => age > 35,
    filterFn3 = year => year === 1955,
    fns = [filterFn1, filterFn2, filterFn2],
    whatever = ... // final function for mapping
    result = data
        .filter(x => fns.every(f => f(x)))
        .map(whatever);
```

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can do is to combine all those filter functions into one single function, with `reduce`, then call `filter` with the combined function.

```
var combined = [firstFilterFunction, seconfFilterFunction, ...]
                .reduce((x, y) => (z => x(z) && y(z)));
var filtered = myData.filter(combined);
```